# Modem Network DIsconnected. You are now offline

Tags: 11.10, configuration, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

I'm a new user of linux environment. I'm using ubuntu 11.10 and a MTS Mblaze USB modem. I have installed it correctly and it was working good at first but when I restarted my system then I was unable to connect my Modem again. Whenever I want click on that MTS connection, a message prompts up "Modem Network Disconnected. You are now offline." Please help to get me out of this problem.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 2):

A bug report is already created for this problem. It includes a work around also which may work for you. Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/868034.

Answer (score 2):

check your modem manufacturer for example i have huwai E1550

make change to your **"usb_modeswitch.conf"** edit the file byyping  this to terminal

```
sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

to disable the rule place a # at start of the line , example

Quote:

```
# Huawei E1550
 ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1003", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

put a extra # in the front of line  ATTRS(idVender)...........

```
# Huawei E1550
# ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1003", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

save this file and then **restart**

hope this will work because this worked for me . good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command from a terminal:

```
sudo killall modem-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the network daemon's inability to detect the modem settings...aggravated by its lack of real time operability.You could just disconnect it, wait then reconnect it and IF THE NETWORK HAS BEEN RECOGNIZED connect with no trouble at all. If not then you have to set up wvdial using appropriate settings to work(However,Doing so rendered network manager unable to recognize my connection and thus ALL applications were connected EXCEPT SOFTWARE CENTER which relied on identification by network daemon)SETTINGS FOR MTS INDIA;

```
[Dialer cdma]
Stupid Mode = 1
Inherits = Modem0
Password = mts
Username = internet@internet.mtsindia.in
Phone = #777

[Modem0]
Init1 = ATZ
SetVolume = 0
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Baud = 115200
FlowControl = Hardware (CRTSCTS)
Dial Command = ATDT
```

Just replace settings in wvdial conf file and then...