# Not getting connection with iball airway nettsetter in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I have installed iBall Netsetter as per the installation notes provided with.
And it is listed under Mobile broadband.

But while connecting it a message will displays " `MODEM Network Disconnected-you are now offline`".

How to solve this?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/73845/modem-network-disconnected-you-are-now-offline